# working with sql server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, connection-string, database-connection

I am not used to work with SQL Server(usually I just use express). I run it on windows server 2008, iis7.

I have attached the database to my sql server. I made a web site in iis7 but I get this error message.

> Cannot open database "Phaeton.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.

Connectionstring I use

```
<add key="PhaetonConnectionString" value="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Phaeton.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the name of your database, is it Phaeton.mdf? or just Phaeton?

Comment: Phaeton then the .mdf for the file. What that might be the problem? i am going to check it asap when i am at the computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the database I tried to attach was sql express

Comment: You can attach a SQL Express database to a newer version of SQL Server.  You just can't reattach it to the old SQL Express server again afterward.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Integrated Security the SQL connection will use the windows identity which is passed from ASP.NET.

You can either change your security to mixed-mode which will involve removing the integrated security. Or use impersonation (check IIS and your web.config) and grant that user access to the database.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your application in IIS to turn off anonymous access and turn on Windows authentication(If yoy want to use integrated security).

[Access SQL Server Using Windows Integrated Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx)

The other way, you can use a connection string with user/password ... with the appropriate login

Comment: I don't want to use the windows authentication. I rather use a user/password type. Where do I setup that? I am going to have about 5 sites on my server now so is there a way to do seperate user for each site?

Comment: Well, you can create an SQL Login (From Sql Management Studio for example) and you can assign rights to which database and databases objects it has access.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

> Initial Catalog=Phaeton.mdf

In SQL Server Express, you can attach a filename as a local database.  That's not how it works on a production SQL Server.  In non-Express versions you attach a database *permanently*, which it looks like you've already done, and you give it a *logical* name, which is not the same as the primary file name.

I would guess that if the file name was "Phaeton.mdf" then you probably named the database "Phaeton".  In which case that part of the connection string should simply be:

> Initial Catalog=Phaeton

If that's not the right name, you can get a list of database names from the server using the following script:

```
USE master;
SELECT name FROM sys.databases
```